# Finding the logarithmic moment generating function under different probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Q\in M_1(M_1(\Sigma))$, whereby $M_1(\Sigma)$ denotes the space of probability measures on $\Sigma$ and define $Q_n \in M_1(M_1(\Sigma))$ to be the distribution of
$$
\nu =(\nu_1...,\nu_n) \in M_1(\Sigma)^n \mapsto \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \nu_k \in M_1(\Sigma)
$$
under $Q^{\otimes n} \in M_1(M_1(\Sigma)^n).$ We define a new measure $\mu_Q (\Gamma) = \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \nu(\Gamma)Q(d\nu), \Gamma \in B_{\Sigma},$ the Borel sigma algebra on $\Sigma, \nu \in M_1(\Sigma).$ We then set for $\phi \in C_b(\Sigma;\mathbb{R})$, the space of real valued continuous and bounded functions on $\Sigma$,
$$
\Lambda_Q(\phi) = \log\left(\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \exp\left[\int_{\Sigma}\phi \;d\nu\right] Q(d\nu)\right).
$$
We specialize this to the case in which $Q$ is the distribution $\bar\mu$ of $\sigma\in\Sigma \mapsto \delta_{\sigma} \in M_1(\Sigma)$ under some measure $\mu \in M_1(\Sigma).$ Then, $Q_n$ is the distribution $\bar\mu_n$ of the empirical distribution functional
$$
\sigma = (\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n)\in \Sigma^n \mapsto L_n(\sigma)= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n \delta_{\sigma_m}
$$
under $\mu^{\otimes n}.$ I want to see why the measure $\mu_Q$ introduced above coincides in this particular case with $\mu.$ In particular, I need to show that the logarithmic moment generating function $\Lambda_Q$ above transforms into $\Lambda_{\bar\mu}(\phi) = \log[\int_{\Sigma} \exp[\phi]d\mu]$ in this special case. Given that for $\nu = \delta_{\sigma}$ it holds that $ \int_{\Sigma} \phi d\nu = \phi,$ one gets $\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \exp (\int_{\Sigma} \phi d\nu) Q(d\nu) = \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \exp [\phi] Q(d\nu).$ I do not know how to go from here. In particular,I do not see how the measure $\mu$ looks like and why it should coincide with $\mu_Q.$ Can you provide some help or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: Your question does not refer to $Q_n$ at any point. Why do you introduce it?

Comment: I am reading a book. I want to understand it. It is not easy to read it. This is my last question. I am trying to understand by myself where it is possible. I did not introduce $Q_n.$  The two scenarios presented above are typical ones in probability theory. How the one goes into the other, I guess that is the aim here.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't want to stop you from asking questions here! That is what it is for. I just meant that it can sometimes be helpful to take a bit more time to ponder as it helps you more when you solve it yourself and it spares others the time :) But when you are tried everything and are still stuck, then that's what SE is there for!

Comment: And you **did** introduce $Q_n$ in the question (I didn't mean that you invented it). But in the final question, you do not seem to care about $Q_n$ any more. So I was wondering why you defined it in the first place. The question (to me) seems to be solely on $\mu$ and $\mu_Q$ which are both independent of $n$.

Comment: I stated it as it is stated in the book. It tells us about a sequence of measures. It must not be used though. For completeness reasons I included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I will concentrate on the question asked and therefore ignore the parts that pertain to $Q_n$ which seems to be unrelated.

Somehow, it seems that your confusion comes from difficulties in understanding some of the definitions of the objects. I strongly recommend writing down the definitions and going through them carefully. Maybe do some examples with easy measures where everything is explicit.

For example, it might be a good exercise that if $\mu$ is a measure and $\nu = \mu\circ f^{-1}$ is its push-forward under some function $f:\Sigma_1 \rightarrow \Sigma_2$, then
$$
\int_{\Sigma_2} g\;d\nu = \int_{\Sigma_1} g\circ f \;d\mu
$$
for all $\nu$-integrable functions $g:\Sigma_2\rightarrow \mathbb R$. The rest of the answer relies exclusively on this property.

We consider some Polish space $\Sigma$ with a probability distribution $\mu$ on it. Then, we define $\overline{\mu} := \mu \circ f^{-1}$ as the push-forward of $\mu$ under
$$
f: \Sigma \longrightarrow M_1(\Sigma),\quad \sigma \mapsto \delta_\sigma.
$$
Then (changing the notation $\mu_Q$ to $\rho$ in order to avoid confusion with the other $\mu$), we define the measure $\rho$ on $\Sigma$ through
$$
\rho(A) := \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \nu(A)\;\overline{\mu}(d\nu) = \int_\Sigma \delta_\sigma(A)\;\mu(d\sigma) = \int_A \mu(d\sigma) = \mu(A),
$$
where we used the definition of a push-forward and the fact that $\delta_\sigma(A) = 1$ if $\sigma\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. In particular, $\rho = \mu$.

The next quantity of interest is defined for $Q\in M_1(M_1(\Sigma))$ and $\phi\in C_b(\Sigma)$ through
$$
\Lambda_Q(\phi) := \log\left(\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \exp\left[ \int_\Sigma \phi\;d\nu\right]\; Q(d\nu)\right).
$$
The above means that
\begin{align*}
\Lambda_{\overline{\mu}}(\phi) &= \log\left(\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \exp\left[ \int_\Sigma \phi \;d\nu\right]\; \overline{\mu}(d\nu)\right)\\
&= \log\left(\int_\Sigma \exp\left[ \int_\Sigma \phi\; d\delta_\sigma\right] \;d\mu(\sigma)\right)\\
&= \log\left(\int_\Sigma \exp\Big( \phi(\sigma) \Big)\;d\mu(\sigma)\right)\\
&= \log \left(\int_\Sigma \exp\circ\phi \;d\mu\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Many thanks. I appreciate your efforts. In the third and second equality from the end, is it the same to write $d\mu(\sigma)$ and $\mu(d\sigma)$ ?

Comment: I also have e general question. There are at least three measures mentioned in each scenario. If we take the first one as an example, they say, $Q_n$ is the distribution of that map under $Q^n \in M_1(M_1(\Sigma)).$ Which measure/distribution represents what ?

Comment: @user996159 Whether to use $\mu(d\sigma)$ or $d\mu(\sigma)$ depends on your own preferences. I tend to use $d\mu(\sigma)$ when the variable is clear, whereas $\mu(d\sigma)$ when it is not immediately clear over which variable is integrated. In this case, there is probably no confusion (and thus both notations are fine), but if one considers parametrized measures $\mu(x, dy)$, the notation $d\mu(x,y)$ would be very confusing.

Comment: @user996159 I do not entirely understand your second question. Could you explain a bit more? And please consider using the $\otimes$ symbol to differentiate $Q^{\otimes n}$ from the variable $Q^n$ with a simple superscript. I have only very rarely seen a product measure being denoted by a simple superscript.

Comment: I want to understand the role of each of these distributions. For any finite $n$ presumably $Q_n$ assigns a probability to the random vector of measures $(\nu_1,...,\nu_n)$ which is then considered in building the empirical mean. Does this mean that one picks randomly the measures $\nu_i$ in view of building the empirical mean? If so, why there would be randomness ? They say, this is done "under the $Q^{\otimes n} \in M_1(M_1(\Sigma))$." What do they mean by this ?

Comment: Similarly as in the simple case treated in the answer, it is meant as a push-forward. This time, the function is $f(\nu_1,\dots, \nu_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \nu_i$ from $M_1(\Sigma)$ to $M_1(\Sigma)$ and then $Q_n := Q^{\otimes n}\circ f^{-1}$. That means that $Q^{\otimes n}$ assigns probabilities to the vector $(\nu_1, \dots, \nu_n)$, but in the end the book only cares about the distribution of $f(\nu_1, \dots, \nu_n)$. The measure $Q_n$ lives on $M_1(\Sigma)$, so that it gives probabilities to some measure $\nu$ when it is in the image of $f$.

Comment: Should it rather be $Q^{\otimes n} \in M_1^{\otimes n}(M_1(\Sigma))$ instead of $Q^{\otimes n} \in M_1(M_1(\Sigma))$ ? I found a typo. It should be $M_1(M_1(\Sigma)^{\otimes n})$

Comment: True, it should indeed be $Q^{\otimes n} \in M_1(M_1(\Sigma)^n)$.

Comment: I still do not understand the randomness in the map. What is random in the process of choosing probability measures and building their empirical mean ?

Comment: I guess, what you mean, is that each distribution $\nu_i$ is associated with some random variable whose law is precisely $\nu_i.$ Thus, by the push-forward measure, one assigns probabilities under the measure $Q_n$ to the events under say $X_i$ whose distribution is $\nu_i$. I hope you would agree.

Comment: My last question: by the weal law of large numbers and given the second countability of the weak topology on $M_1(\Sigma),$ I want to show the weak convergence $Q_n \implies \delta_{\mu_Q}.$ By definition, one should show $\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \phi Q_n(d\nu) \rightarrow \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} \phi d\delta_{\mu_Q} = \phi(\mu_Q), \forall \phi \in C_b.$ What is the best approach ? I am not sure if the right hand side integral is $\phi(\mu_Q)$ given the evaluation domain of $\phi.$

Comment: If one chooses the characteristic function based way, one has to show, $\int_{M_1(\Sigma)} e^{it\nu} Q_n(d\nu) \rightarrow \int_{M_1(\Sigma)} e^{it\nu} \delta_{\mu_Q}(d\nu) = \frac{e^{it\mu_Q}}{it}.$ How should I go from here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151011/discussion-between-mushu-nrek-and-user996159).

Comment: Another way to show weak convergence of measures $Q_n$ is to prove $\lim \sup Q_n(F) \leq \delta_{\mu_Q}(F), \forall  F$ closed in $M_1(\Sigma).$ For $\mu_Q \in F,$ the inequality holds since $Q_n(A) \leq 1 \forall A \in M_1(\Sigma).$ Let $\mu_Q \not\in F.$ Then, $\delta_{\mu_Q}(F) = 0.$ Thus, we need to show, $\lim \sup Q_n (F) = 0.$ I do not know how to show this.

Comment: @user996159 see the chat

Comment: Thanks. Can we meet in chat ?

Comment: @user996159 the chat is still open...